# Are there are any go clients for Google sites

Tags: go, google-api, google-sites

are there are any golang clients to get all the contents from google sites as we have

```html
"google.golang.org/api/googleapi"
```

for google drive,any suggestions on how to get all the contents of googlesites using golang

Answer (score 2):

There is no Go client for Google Sites.

There is a general [Google Sites API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/code?hl=pl) but it only works with an old version of Google Sites.

Comment: are there are anywhich way i can get contents from latest googlesites

Comment: I am not aware of any, consider using a web scraping library.